# How to detect if Doctrine query is from cache?

Tags: symfony, doctrine, predis

I'm trying to use [Doctrine Result Caching](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/caching.html#result-cache) with Redis and Predis and [SncRedisBundle](https://github.com/snc/SncRedisBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md#doctrine-caching) and Symfony.

I would like to know if my cache+doctrine+redis+predis+SncRedisBundle configuration is set properly

```
snc_redis:
    clients:
        default:
            type: predis
            alias: default
            dsn: redis://localhost
    doctrine:
        metadata_cache:
            client: default
            entity_manager: default          
            document_manager: default        
        result_cache:
            client: default
            entity_manager: [default, read]  
        query_cache:
            client: default
            entity_manager: default
```

because below query display what expected, but how do I know if it come from cache or not?

```
$query = $repository->createQueryBuilder('p')
    ->where('p.id < :id')
    ->setParameter('id', '100')
    ->orderBy('p.id', 'ASC')
    ->getQuery()
    ->useQueryCache(true)    
    ->useResultCache(true); 

$products = $query->getResult();
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in this test https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/tests/Doctrine/Tests/ORM/Functional/ResultCacheTest.php#L40 there is no function to do this.

You can however achieve this by either defining your own cacheId or using <strike>`->getQuery()->getResultCacheId()`</strike>**deprecated** `->getQuery()->getQueryCacheProfile()->getCacheKey()` and `->getQuery()->getResultCacheDriver()->fetch($cacheKey)`

source: https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/AbstractQuery.php#L945